# Activity missing in manifest when declair

Tags: java, android, manifest

There is two arrows as you see in picture ..
one indicate to Activities in my project
other one indicate to recommended activity to declare in manifest ..
but there is no recommended activity except " StreamingActivity "
when i run my application ,, application show me that message " Unfortunately , application has stopped "

[image]

this code for publisheractivity

```
package khaabbas.huthaifa.com.talk_listen;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.red5pro.streaming.R5Connection;
import com.red5pro.streaming.R5Stream;
import com.red5pro.streaming.R5StreamProtocol;
import com.red5pro.streaming.config.R5Configuration;
import com.red5pro.streaming.source.R5Camera;
import com.red5pro.streaming.source.R5Microphone;
//import android.graphics.Camera;

public class PublishFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public static android.support.v4.app.Fragment newInstance() {
    PublishFragment fragment = new PublishFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


public PublishFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public R5Configuration configuration;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    configuration = new R5Configuration(R5StreamProtocol.RTSP, "localhost",  8554, "live", 1.0f);
    configuration.setLicenseKey("NBZF-UFM2-GCEP-OUYZ");
    configuration.setBundleID(getActivity().getPackageName());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_publish, container, false);
    return v;
}
protected Camera camera;
protected boolean isPublishing = false;
protected R5Stream stream;

private void preview() {
    camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surface.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    preview();
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Button publishButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
    publishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onPublishToggle();
        }
    });
}

private void onPublishToggle() {
    Button publishButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.publishButton);
    if(isPublishing) {
        stop();
    }
    else {
        start();
    }
    isPublishing = !isPublishing;
    publishButton.setText(isPublishing ? "stop" : "start");
}

public void start() {
    camera.stopPreview();

    stream = new R5Stream(new R5Connection(configuration));
    stream.setView((SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));

    R5Camera r5Camera = new R5Camera(camera, 320, 240);
    R5Microphone r5Microphone = new R5Microphone();

    stream.attachCamera(r5Camera);
    stream.attachMic(r5Microphone);

    stream.publish("red5prostream", R5Stream.RecordType.Live);
    camera.startPreview();
}

public void stop() {
    if(stream != null) {
        stream.stop();
        camera.startPreview();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isPublishing) {
        onPublishToggle();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: That is PublisherFragment, not PublisherActivity, and it is not an Activity, it is a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Comment: the fragment cannot be registered to `Manifest`.

Comment: Please read this document it may be helpful to solve your issue. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 0):

Remove both this activity because u used only single activity it define activity and two other is fragment.

```
    <activity android:name=".S"/>
    <activity android:name=".Sub"/>
```

and fragment call used below code..

```
         Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare fragment on manifest, remove fragment declaration from manifest because you are declare fragment within  section in manifest file.